# how to retrieve all thumbnails of pdf from mysql database using php

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, thumbnails

hello to all i want to fetch all thumbnails(images) from mysql database. i.e i have pdf file in local folder and i created the thumbnails for those. Now i want to show all these images/thumbnails on page so that one can see all pdf thumbnails.  In db, i used local folder image path to retrieve. Can anyone please tell me how to do that.

```
include 'connection.php';

$sql1=mysqli_query($con,"select path,topic,thumbnails from `retrive-thumbnails`") or die(mysqli_error($con));

$count=0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql1))
{

echo "<div><img src=\"thumbnails/".$row['thumbnails']."\" /></div>";
$count++;
}

/*$result1=mysqli_fetch_array($sql1);$filepath=$result1["path"];
$filetopic=$result1["topic"]; //echo $filetopic;
$thumbnails=$result1["thumbnails"];
@readfile($thumbnails);
*/mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: What kind of output are you expecting? You are using `html`, with an `image header` and also want to have `PDF`. What are you trying to do.

Comment: as i stated in que, i want to show all thumbnails(images)  from mysql database.

Comment: Then remove the `header("Content-type: image/jpeg");` part. You're creating an webpage with images, not an actual image. If you post that header, the browser expects an image.

Comment: okey. i updated que so u will be more clear on my que.